# iOS Safari WebSockets : huge latency when sending messages at short intervals

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, websocket, latency

I just found a very annoying thing about using websockets on iOS Safari (iOS 5.0.1). When sending two messages at very close interval (think 30 - 40ms, for example, sending a message at mousedown on a button and one on mouseup) the two messages arrive at 200 to 300ms of interval on the server.
This makes using WebSockets on iOS really painful for making a remote controller for example...

I'm affraid I know the answer, but is there anyway to make it work better ? It seems like it's a bug in the Websockets implementation of Safari but could it also be coming from the WiFi implementation (I hardly think so...) ?

Comment: I don't think I've seen this with 4.X on an old iPhone 3G. That would be really disappointing if Apple has decided to hobble their WebSockets implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out some kind of workaround, and that the websockets implementation of Safari Mobile behaves even weirder than what I already found out.

While making some ping tests to validate my theory, I realised that I didn't have the problem anymore. Then I tested again with my original code and I had the same problem again.

Then I realised what changed in my code, compared to the ping test : the server never sends anything to the client. So, whenever my server receives a message from the iPhone, he sends a message back to it. That way, the latency disappears. It's really weird and there's probably something to be done to fix that issue, but in the meantime, this will do...

Comment: This suggests that nagle's isn't disabled. Found this post when looking into how to disable it on iOS browsers (same happening on chrome). For some reason I can't seem to do that.